# User Defined Aggregate Function in T-SQL instead of .net assembly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

aggregate functions are useful, e.g.:

```
select FinancialYear, PLFolder, Sum(PLDelta) SumDelta 
from PL group by FinancialYear, PLFolder
```

however, sometimes I need do more complex calculation, such as, calculating the volatility.

This could be done by a User Defined Aggregate Function, programmed in C#, compiled as a CLR assembly, and then imported into MSSQL.

Is it possible to do it in pure T-SQL?

Comment: Isn't volatility easily calculated with the other aggregate functions?

Comment: this is just an example, for example, to calculate a quantile number, but instead of following mssql built-in "top 5%" logic, requiring some interpolation...

Comment: No, it's not possible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.**

The only way to write custom aggregates is through SQLCLR. There are technical reasons behind this limitation, primarily related to the need of an aggregate to have *state*.